# confused about haskell function to get length of list

Tags: haskell

I am going through the [school of haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell/1-haskell-basics) basics and on the functions on lists section it uses this expression to get the length of the list

```
intListLength (_:xs) = 1 + intListLength xs
```

I have tried manipulating this with different values where the one is and it seems to be multiplying even though the expression is with addition although the function is returning the correct value for the length of the list.

I was hoping someone would be able to explain what's happening here.

Comment: Do you have a terminator like `intListLength [] = 0`?

Comment: yes that is the terminator that is used in the function and it runs appropriately with the correct result i just don't understand this line

Comment: In `(_:xs)` the `xs` matches the tail of the list (the remaining part except the first item) so you have a `1` for the head item and then add (`+`)  it with the result of the same task run for the tail (`xs`) up until there is no more tail (terminator condition).

Comment: That makes perfect sense that explains when i changed it to a 2 it made it 10 when the list was 5 in length thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

```
intListLength :: [Integer] -> Integer
intListLength [] = 0
intListLength (x:xs) = 1 + intListLength xs
```

As the document you linked explains:

> The first clause says that the length of an empty list is 0. The second clause says that if the input list looks like (x:xs), that is, a first element xconsed onto a remaining list xs, then the length is one more than the length of xs.
>
> Since we don’t use x at all we could also replace it by an underscore: intListLength (_:xs) = 1 + intListLength xs.

The function `intListLength` is adding `1` to a running sum for every element in the list. Every time `intListLength` is called, an element is popped off the list, and a `1` is added to a running total created by the recursive call on the remaining elements of the list. When there are no more elements in the list, the empty list function head is matched and a `0` is added to the total. At that point, the total is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
   intListLength (_:xs) = 1 + intListLength xs
```

In plain English this means "the length of a list starting with any element (`_`) followed by the elements `xs` is `1` plus then length of the list `xs`".